# Split arbitrary length series of divs into columns using HTML or CSS without CSS3

Tags: html, css

I want to split a series of divs vertically:

My HTML might look like this:

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
...
<div>G</div>
```

I want them to look like this

```
A D G
B E
C F
```

The number of elements is arbitrary and I would like to avoid having to add extra attributes on certain of the divs if possible, as that would increase complexity greatly.

I've looked at the CSS3 columns option, but is there any way to do this without CSS3? I would prefer to avoid Javascript libraries as well.

Comment: Can you just use floats and specify widths?

Comment: What about them listing horizontally, instead of vertically? So row 1 would be ABC, row 2 would be DEF...?

Comment: are the elements of variable height and you want for them to render like a newspaper column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want it to be dynamic, there is no sane way to replicate such a layout without relying on [CSS3 Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns) or JS (plugin or otherwise).

tbowman's suggestion of using floats and specified widths would result in a different order of items:

```
A B C
D E F
G
```

This could however work perfectly well if you could use jquery to <del>rearrange the items</del> wrap items into columns as needed (the logic could be replicated in vanilla javascript). Bonus points if you use AJAX to retrieve this content and wrap content into columns *before* they're added to DOM so that there's no annoying flicker.

```
var $container = $('#container'); //assuming this is the parent
var $content = $container.children();
var itemsPerColumn = (Math.ceil($content.length / 3));
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $content.slice(i * itemsPerColumn, (i + 1) * itemsPerColumn)
    .wrapAll('<div class="column" />');
}
```

[Fiddle'd](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/Y88Vs/) with delayed rendering for comparison. Page would remain usable with "normal" layout if js fails for some reason.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this on the server-side. There really aren't any great client-side solutions for this I think.

Answer (score -1):

Without CSS3, the best thing to do is to specify a width on all divs, and whenever you want a linebreak include a class ".clear":

```
.clear { clear:both; display:block; height:0; }
```

Then, you can say Athis is on the next line
For width you can use css classes with predefined widths, if you don't want CSS3